# Access files in remote computer with php

Tags: php, csv, remote-access

I need to create an application using php which is hosted in a server and need to communicate with a csv file located in clients local machine. Is there any way we could do this ? How can I connect to a remote csv file ? Is this possible ?

Comment: Can't the client upload the csv

Comment: Usually, this is a client that communicates with the server, the server cannot directly call client. Or you'll need to install a server on the machine that hosts the csv file.

Comment: We cant use file upload here. Thats the problem as well. Can we do something with noip.com ?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to _accomplish_? Focus on the problem, not what you think the solution might be.

Answer (score 0):

Server machine accessing a csv file directly from a client machine is not a good idea. It's a security threat indeed. Consider you are navigating some website and it's server is able to access your computer's file system!!!

There are various alternatives to achieve this, some of these might be:

1. Make the user upload csv files to server in order to make it
   available to the server application
2. If the client and server are in the same network, then share the
       folder on client machine to make it accessible from the server

etc... I would have preferred the first option as mentioned above.

Comment: We cant use file upload here. Thats the problem as well. Can we do something with noip.com ?

Answer (score 0):

As @AnthonyB mentioned in comment under your question, server can't directly call client, and that is true. Server is called "server" as it serves requests from the client.

To be able to give away files to remote requests, your client needs its own server application, like Apache HTTPD for example.

In case if you need continuously request client's server to collect files with your PHP server, what you are looking for called "worker". One of AWS tools called Elastic Beanstalk offers possibility to choose a server or a worker application during start up wizard for PHP. It is pretty straight forward and easy to use.

Please note, that your client must have dedicated IP address or use Dynamic DNS approach by pushing its IP to a DB (or directly to a server) where worker will take it from.

If you don't need dedicated worker, you can configure CRON JOB to send requests to clients server applications.

IMHO, all that scenario worth it only if you are building corporate grade application. In most cases (and if you do REALLY need to collect files from clients) you have to install Apache + PHP server on the client side and make this guys to wait for request from YOUR remote php server. Without it, you can not get files from clients computers via browser without user input interactions. At least legally :)